# Sankalpam for Avani avittam

Tags: karma

Detailed **Sankalpam for Avanivavittam** this year 2023,
at *Hiroshima, Japan.*
Vadagalai,
Azhagiyasingar madam.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question must be answered by a professional Hindu practitioner or an accredited religious organization.